# [strcat&malloc&free], when I use strcat(), pointer seems not NULL even I deliberately made it to be(no extra assignment)?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

as the title, I made a demo to describe my confusion.

if I replace [strcat ]to [stacpy], I can get what's obvious, which is

@

@

@

so I suspected the problem comes up with [strcat].

```
void main(){
    for(int i=0; i<3 ;i++){

        char* str = (char*)malloc(200*sizeof(char));

        if(str == NULL){
            printf("malloc failed. \n");
            return;
        }

        strcat(str, "@ ");
        printf("%s\n", str);

        free(str);
        str = NULL;
    }
}
```

In my expectation, I should get:

@

@

@

---

but what I got is:

(1)
@

xK`▒

xK`▒

and every time are not the same:

(2)
@

x▒

x▒

(3)
@

xk▒▒

xk▒▒

Comment: google first please. The duplicate answer I found is the first google search result for `strcpy strcat` for me.

Comment: Sorry, and thans. I will try be not this lazy next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)

> *The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string **to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of `dest`,** and then adds a terminating null byte. [...]*

Note the emphasis, the first argument, the destination, should be a *string*.

The problem is, `malloc()` does not return the pointer to memory block which is initialized. So, there's no guarantee that there is a null-terminator anywhere in the returned memory block. So, in search of the null-terminator, your program will access past the allocated memory, and attempt to access invalid memory location, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) or UB. You said

> *and every time are not the same:*

that's what UB is precisely.

Related, from `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.4

> *The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and
>   whose value is indeterminate.*

You should use `calloc()` if you want to use the returned pointer as *string*, as the memory block is zero-initialized.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems like I don't have solid foundation at all. Not just gave me the solution and also the method how to generate it, amazing!